# Play music from PC on Android

Tags: wi-fi, music, music-player

If I have shared a folder on my computer that has all my music in it, is it possible, when connected to the same Wifi network with my phone (Nexus One, Gingerbread), to play this music on my phone?

In case I need to use an application that mounts the shared folder on my phone, it would be extra awesome if it would mount automatically when connecting to that network.

Comment: I assume this is a Windows shared folder (that is, an "SMB share") that you're talking about?

Comment: @Ilari yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be something like the [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) app. You actually don't even need the music to be on a shared drive for that one to work, you just need VLC installed on the PC and a wifi LAN to share (or 3G and some network security know-how).

There are also some third-party apps that are designed specifically for the streaming aspect of VLC, without the local playback features, such as [VLC Streamer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hobbyistsoftware.android.vlcrstreamer_free).

Answer (score 1):

ES File Explorer will let you play media files...but I think you have to pick them one at a time to play them...not sure if you can play a list of songs....

Answer (score 1):

Linux has an file system wrapper thingy called `cifs` that allows it to mount an SMB share (Windows shared folder) transparently as a standard folder to the file system.

Looks like there's an android app for creating and managing cifs mounts - [CifsManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=ws.plattner.cifsmanager). Using it, I assume you could make your Android device see all the files in the shares just like they would be on your memory card. The app does list "playing music" as an example use case in it's description, so I expect it could be used for this purpose.

I haven't looked at how it works yet, but intend to now that you made me interested in the use case. :) I'll edit the answer when I've had time to test this.

Note that the app **requires root**. Also, don't know if it can automatically reconnect the shares when they become available. And I'm not sure if it messes up the Android music player or file management system or whatever if the mounted files it was accessing suddenly become disconnected (I would expect that Android can handle it, though).

Comment: Please update the link for the app. The current one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man you could try [Samba Network Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threecats.sambaplayer&hl=en) - it was specifically designed for this purpose. Still in development but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winamp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp&feature=search_result) to sync your music wirelessly between your phone and that share.  You can find [a guide on how to do it here](http://androidforums.com/android-media/79959-how-flawlessly-sync-your-music-your-android-winamp-56k-warning.html).

Comment: Won't syncing using Winamp merely transfer the music from PC to the device? OR does syncing imply streaming?

Comment: Yes, it will copy the music over, but it'll do it automatically when Winamp is launch and on that wifi network.  The op does not specify that he was wanting streaming, but "when connected to the same Wifi network with my phone, to play this music on my phone?" This solution should meet those guidelines

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. The music folder is like 70GB, so copying it is not an option. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @Aistina, you were specific enough.  "when connected"... pretty obviously means "I don't want to copy it, I just want to play it".

Comment: Can we have an updated link for the app? The current one seems to be dead.

Comment: Still works for me? You mean to the market/play store? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp&feature=search_result I'll update the answer

Comment: I just tried an online proxy server and the link still seemsto be broken: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFuQ.png , http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn2rG.png I don't know why though.

Comment: @Firelord Not sure, are you located outside the US?

Comment: Yes. But I thought Play Store imposed geo-restriction only when you're browsing apps using Google Play app. Edit: I now tried two proxy servers claiming to be from USA and the result is still same. Anyway, I'll not stress it further. If another user complains then you can take action based on that.

Answer (score 0):

A [Squeezebox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezebox_Server) server ([download](http://www.mysqueezebox.com/download)) running on the Pc will allow any device on the network to connect to the [MP3 stream it broadcasts](http://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Remote_streaming). You can add songs to the playlist via the web interface from the PC or your phone's browser, or install one of the Android Squeezebox controller apps like [Squeeze Commander](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.cedata.android.squeezecommander).

See also this previous question [Client-Server Android audio remote](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/client-server-android-audio-remote)

Answer (score 0):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org) is also a great way to share music with you Android device over WiFi or even the Internet. There is also an [Subsonic Android App.](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.sourceforge.subsonic.androidapp)

Or you could use [Google Music](http://music.google.com), which is currently US only.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the preview version of 'Soumi Music Player' at the following link for playing MP3 files from your network shared folder.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Soumi-music-player-preview