# Android tablet as music remote

Tags: wi-fi, music-player, linux, remote-control

I imagine a setup where I use an android tablet computer as a remote control for my hifi system - at least for selecting music. I have connected a low-power, cheap and small linux computer to the amp. The low-powered computer holds all music on a USB stick, SSD or similar. The computer has no screen or keyboard permanently attached.

Can something like this work? All solutions I have found on the net require streaming from a NAS or the internet (internet radio) - e.g. Sonos. Ideas regarding hardware and software are welcome.

Comment: This previous topic covers similar but not quite the same ground as your question, might be some pointers there http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/client-server-android-audio-remote

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like [VLC Remote](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hobbyistsoftware.android.vlcremote_usfree). It can apparently even be configured to work with an MPlayer install instead of VLC if you prefer (according to [this project](https://github.com/peterseverin/RMPlayer), at least). There's also a remote app for [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) available, and you can find it [in the Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.songbirdremote) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [mpd](http://mpd.wikia.com/) (music player daemon). It doesn't require X and there are lots of different clients/remotes for all kinds of operating systems [including Android](https://market.android.com/search?q=mpd).